# Compare all but last N Columns across two files in bash

Tags: bash, awk, diff

I have 2 files: one with 18 columns; another with many more. I need to find the rows that mismatch on ONLY the first 18 columns while ignoring the rest in the other file. However, I need to preserve and print the entire row (cut will not work).

File 1:

```
F1 F2 F3....F18
A  B  C.... Y
AA BB CC... YY
```

File 2:

```
F1 F2 F3... F18... F32
AA BB CC... YY... 123
AAA BBB CCC... YYY...321
```

Output Not In File 1:

`AAA BBB CCC YYY...321`

Output Not In File 2:

```
 A  B  C...Y
```

If possible, I would like to use diff or awk with as few loops as possible.

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you showed us a complete example using, for example, matching 3 columns out of 5.

Comment: I was attempting to explain with fields. I guess assume F1 F2 F3... F18 are the first 4 columns and F32 is the 5th that ONLY exists in the second file. I only want to compare across the first four, BUT, I want to preserve that fifth column and carry it over to the output. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: [edit] your question to show **concise, testable** sample input and expected output. i.e. some input we could run a potential solution against (so get rid of all `...`s to start with)  to produce the output you also show. Any other explanation/info in addition to that is nice but that's the key thing we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{k=""; for(i=1; i<=18; i++) k=k SUBSEP $i} FNR==NR{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' file1 file2
```

- For each row in both files we are first creating a key by concatenating first `18` fields
- We are then storing this key in an associative array while iterating first file
- Finally we print each row from 2nd file when this new key value is not found in our associative array.

Comment: How do I know I am only printing the second file? Just curious. awk is still a mystery to me.

Comment: We are printing row from 2nd file only because `file2` is 2nd file in the list after `awk` command. `!(k in a)` is the action that makes awk print each row from 2nd file

Comment: Worked as far as I can tell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep:

```
grep -vf file1 file2
grep -vf <(cut -d" "  -f1-18 file2) file1
```

Answer (score 0):

to get set differences between two files, you'll need little more, similar to @anubhava's answer

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{f1[$0]; next}  
              {k=$1; for(i=2;i<=18;i++) k=k FS $i; 
               if(k in f1) delete f1[k]; 
               else f2[$0]} 
           END{print "not in f1"; 
               for(k in f2) print k; 
               print "\nnot in f2"; 
               for(k in f1) print k}' file1 file2
```

can be re-written to preserve order in file2

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{f1[$0]; next}  
               {k=$1; for(i=2;i<=18;i++) k=k FS $i; 
                if(k in f1) delete f1[k]; 
                else {if(!p) print "not in f1";  
                      f2[$0]; print; p=1}} 
            END{print "\nnot in f2"; 
                for(k in f1) print k}' file1 file2
```